# PHP - Executing say function from mac shell / terminal

Tags: php, macos, terminal, text-to-speech

I am trying to make a simple php script that takes text from user input and then uses mac's terminal 'say' function (text-to-speach) to read the text aloud.

The only resource I've been able to find which specifically addresses this is from [2003](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031113181603909).

A very simple solution suggested in that topic was:

```
    <html><body>
    <form method="post">
    Say: <input type="text" name="text" size="40">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body></html>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
        exec('say "'.$_POST['text'].'"');
        }
    ?>
```

I have tried using 'system' instead of 'exec' without luck.
I really have no clue how to troubleshoot this. Could it be something with access and not the code? Any kind of help on how to find out why it won't work would be great, thanks.

Comment: It would only play the sound on the server running the php script not on the client PC?

Comment: I want it to play on the client PC if posible.

Comment: php is a server-side programming language. If you use in your script an exec function, that command is execute in the server. You can't do that with php. Try with javascript there are a lot of library for text to speech http://goo.gl/R5MCH.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.
Actually I only need to run this locally. I'm just doing it in php because it's the only language I have any basic knowledge of, and because I want to save the message in a database.

So I want to save the message to the db and playback the audio in one step if possible. Could I run php locally?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use -o option of say command that allow to save the output on a audio file. At this [link](http://goo.gl/HVoHc) there is a bash script that create a mp3 file from a file text; it is simple to readapt the script to take the string not from a file. The you allow the user to download it or execute on a web page with this simple code
`<embed height="50" width="100" src="example.mp3">`
replacing example.mp3 with the path of the mp3 file created before.

Comment: this is the [official manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html) of say command